# AngularJS : nested ng-repeat peformance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a requirement where data is dynamic and very hierarchical (3- 4 level deep) where each inner level can be a list which can again contain list (please look at my template below). Everything looks good in terms of performance upto 2 ng-repeat but performance degrade sharply for level 3 onwards ng-repeat.

```
<div class="struct-property">
   <div ng-repeat="structGroup in triple.properties track by $index">
        <div ng-repeat="props in structGroup track by $index">
            <simpleproperty triple="props"></simpleproperty>
            <multiplevalueproperty triple="props"></multiplevalueproperty>
            <div ng-if="props.isStructProperty">
                <div class="struct-property">
                    ......
                    <div ng-repeat="structGroupInner in props.properties track by $index">
                        <div ng-repeat="propsInner in structGroupInner track by $index ">
                            <simpleproperty triple="propsInner"></simpleproperty>
                            <multiplevalueproperty triple="propsInner">                       </multiplevalueproperty>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>

Please Note: that I have only static data
```

I used "track by" but not sure if I used it correctly. I did tried to log if DOM is getting recreated with children ng-repeat and I do see that with every nested ng-repeat, parent DOM is getting regenerated and thats the reason performance is very bad.

I also tried to refactor my data so that I can avoid nested ng-repeat but unfortunately I cannot refactor it further because it as a RDF-JSON representation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you used incorrectly "track by", instead of $index you should use a value that identifies the item that's being repeated.

Comment: Does the data change "on-the-fly" all the time or do you poll the data for changes or do you load it initially and then never again until reloading. Maybe this is helpful: https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-performance-large-applications#7-list-problems

Comment: @KonstantinKrass,thank you for the links and very helpfule in debugging my performance issue